# Allocate Big file

Tags: java

I need allocate file with size near 50 gigabytes, but this code:

```
RandomAccessFile out = new RandomAccessFile("C:\\hello.txt", "rw");
out.setLength(50 * 1024 * 1024 * 1024); // 50 giga-bytes
```

Throws exception:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.io.IOException: Попытка поместить указатель на файл перед началом файла
    at java.io.RandomAccessFile.setLength(Native Method)
    at Experiment.main(Experiment.java:8)
```

: Attempting to move the file pointer before the beginning of the file.

When I trying allocate 50 megabytes  such exception not throws.
Free space of disk is much greater then needed file size.

Comment: 50 gb (50 * 1024^3) is bigger than the maximal size of an integer (2^32) so you can't use such a big file size in java

Comment: Yes you can have such a big file by using a long operand.

Comment: FYI if you specify `C:/hello.txt` Java will convert / to \

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You need to define the size as a `long` by using the `L` suffix:

```
out.setLength(50L * 1024L * 1024L * 1024L);
```

The problem is that by default, numeric literals are of `int` type and 50G is outside of its range, so the result of the multiplication overflows. The actual value passed to the `setLength()` is `-2147483648`.

In more detail, the result type of multiplication (as well as other numeric operations) is defined by the most general of its operands, so you don't actually need to add the `L` suffix to every one of them. It is sufficient to add it to only just of them (the first one is a sensible choice):

```
long wrong = 50 * 1024 * 1024 * 1024; // -2147483648
long right = 50L * 1024 * 1024 * 1024; // 53687091200
```

Comment: Say, is there a limit about the file size here? In some cases, it's 2GB, but is it true here too, or there is a much much larger limit (of Long)?